# Page isn't working and returns HTTP error 500 in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a site built in CodeIgniter that works totally fine on my localhost, but upon migrating site to an online server on a subdomain it gives "page isn't working, http://sub.domain.com is unable to handle the request.HTTP error 500"

I also changed `base_url` from `localhost/school/` to `sub.domain.com`, and
database credentials are also fine.

Here is my htaccess code:

[image]

Comment: Check you site's log file for an error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: why 2 answers??