# Transfer CodeIgniter project local to server, admin panel not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I create CodeIgniter project on my local machine (Running perfectly), then I uploaded to a server with its database but I am facing the problem of not found an error while opening admin panel.

I changed config file(for base URL), `database.php`(for database connection).
but I don't know what to change in the `.htaccess` file, I took a default CodeIgniter .htaccess file but it is showing not found error.
htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /crescent_test/ad_crescent/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Please share .htaccess file code.

Comment: Thank you, I added code, please check it. @Gufran Hasan

Comment: Have you got 500 error on browser or something else error ? Could you please send me your browser's error screenshot?

Comment: @Coderfe, Please share url?

Comment: yes i also get 500 error, http://spacegm.com/crescent_test/ad_crescent

Comment: This {RewriteBase /crescent_test/ad_crescent/ } should reflect your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 
 </IfModule>
```

if this does not work then visit below link:

[Page isn't working and returns HTTP error 500 in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456310/page-isnt-working-and-returns-http-error-500-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Thanks but it is not working, giving error like "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456310/page-isnt-working-and-returns-http-error-500-in-codeigniter

Comment: Yes, but i am not having subdomain problem

Comment: Okay, I am sure this will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues

Comment: I follow that link and edit my htaccess file like this :                    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.spacegm\.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$http://spacegm.com/crescent_test/%1/$1[L,NC,QSA]
 </IfModule>                                                                                         
  now it is giving 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

add htaccess file YOUR_ADMIN_FLODER root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /YOUR_ADMIN_FLODER_NAME/
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YOUR_ADMIN_FLODER_NAME/index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YOUR_ADMIN_FLODER_NAME/index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YOUR_ADMIN_FLODER_NAME/index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /YOUR_ADMIN_FLODER_NAME/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it is giving 500 error @shabbirhasan